# java script function and variable based windows.location

Tags: javascript, php

One more silly question. How do I open user profile with click on name of user. 
test1.php page is common profile page for all users. I use `$ui` for check user id in data base and display value as required.

**test1.php** contains

```
function user_link(user_id) {
    var ui=user_id;
    window.location = "test1.php?ui=ui";
}
```

user name link:

```
<span id="user_link" onclick="user_link(21)">'Samantha Dove'</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
function user_link(user_id){
    var ui = user_id;
    window.location = "test1.php?ui=" + ui;
}
```

You need to do concatenation here to append your variable in the URL.

---

Or shorter:

```
function user_link(user_id){
    window.location = "test1.php?ui=" + user_id;
}
```

Or even shorter, *after all*:

```
<a id="user_link" href="test1.php?ui=21">'Samantha Dove'</a>
```